# How to ban or remove unruly or abusive SO cit

Tags: voting

Clearly there needs to be a way I think ?

EDIT: dup of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572113/how-to-deal-with-repeated-abuse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/126742-limit-the-rate-at-which-a-user-can-submit-questions

Comment: I agree but this really belongs on Uservoice.

Answer (score 4):

I have used my 5 offensive tags 
and 12 closure votes today already

Answer (score 4):

It helps if you add "i-am-mad" to your ignored tags.

Comment: Ha, I never thought of doing so.  +1 jpekk.

Answer (score 0):

See the uservoice link posted in comments, these type of posts belong on uservoice or they just contribute to non programming related posts.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572113/how-to-deal-with-repeated-abuse